# How to provide implicit argument to code block without explicitly creating it

Tags: scala

I have a utility object SideEffects, which is passed to a function as implicit argument. It collects all non-db effects to run if my db transaction was successed.

```
def someDbAction(implicit se: SideEffects) {
  ...
  se.add {doSomethingNonDbLike()}
  ...
}
```

The simple way to use this util is to write something like this:

```
implicit val se = new SideEffects()
db.run(someDbAction().transactionally).flatMap(se.run)
```

And I want to write something like this:

```
SideEffects.run {
  someDbAction()
}
```

Is it possible to do it? Just can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your `someDbAction` (or anything at all for that matter!) needs implicit parameter.

Going by your "I want to write ...", it looks like you want this:

```
    object SideEffects() { 
       val se = new SideEffects
       def run[T](action: => T) = 
          db.run(action).transactionally.flatMap(se.run())
    }
```

Then `SideEffects.run { someDbAction() }` (or just `SideEffects.run(someDbAction)`) does exactly what you wanted.

Comment: We need new SideEffects instance for each run. It should be empty before action runs and in flatMap(se.run()) we need to run only sideEffects from that action.

Implicit parameter here is easier to use and better represents the logic of db actions with side effects.

Comment: @EugeneZinin if you need a new instance for each run, replace `val` with `def` above (and/or move it inside `run`). I still don't see how making it implicit makes anything "easier" here.

Comment: If we replace val with def, we will run se.run() on a new empty SideEffects. And I need SideEffects that was passed to the action.

Comment: I just go by the sample you provided. If you want to use what's passed to the action, then pass it to the action and use that. Still don't see what's the problem.